# Link from a document loaded in an IFRAME to open in new TAB-Window

Tags: html, iframe

I have a **main page** and a set of other pages information and links to external sources (various domains - licenses, regulations, GDPR rules, etc. ). These pages are previewed in an **IFRAME** in a **DIV** with *ID="preview"* as a target. I can't find a way to open the links previewed in the IFRAME in the new TAB or Window. I tried to add targets (_top, _blank) to the links. But it doesn't work.

```html
<!-- main -->
<a href="internal_page_1.html" target="preview">Internal page 1</a><br>
<a href="internal_page_2.html" target="preview">Internal page 2</a><br>
<a href="internal_page_3.html" target="preview">Internal page 3</a>

<div id="preview">
 <iframe name="preview"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- external file to be opened in new TAB/Window -->
<p>Blablabla</p>
<a href="https://example.com">Read more: (Link to external source)</a>
```

Comment: changed your tags, this has nothing to do with PHP!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open this in a new window, use target="_blank"

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Read more: (Link to external source)</a>
```

Opens in a new window.

Comment: Sorry, Saw your comment later, that you tried the target field already. There's no reason why the target should not work.

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle which immitates your html, and the link opens in a new window.

https://jsfiddle.net/wmtjhpsf/

Comment: Well, maybe not entirely good described in my post. Thing is:
There is a form on the main page, where various data are collected, incl. some URLs. The form data are stored in individual internal pages. Below the form is the IFRAME where the actually created internal page is shown. It means, there is also the link to an external source. Clicking this link, I want the external page to be opened in new TAB/Window, instead in the IFRAME.